# dojo stateful watch doesn't work

Tags: dojo, watch, stateful

```js
require(["dojo/_base/declare","dijit/_WidgetBase","dojo/Stateful"],function(declare,_WidgetBase,Stateful){
    MaClasse1 = declare([_WidgetBase,Stateful],{
        att1:{'a':'att1_v1','b':'1234'},
        id:'mc1',
        changerAtt1: function(nv){
            this.att1 = nv;
        }
    });

    MaClasse2 = declare([_WidgetBase,Stateful],{
        att1:null,
        id:'mc2',
        constructor: function(att1){
            this.att1 = att1;
        },
        postCreate: function(){
            this.watch('att1',function(name,oldValue, value){ // Doesn't work
                console.log(name,oldValue, value);
            });
        }
    });
    var maClasse1 = new MaClasse1();
    var maClasse2 = new MaClasse2(maClasse1.get('att1'));
    maClasse1.changerAtt1({'a':'att1_v2','b':'56789'});
});
```

Both MaClasse1 and MaClasse2 classes have in common the attribute 'att1', this attribute is a single entity for both classes since it is an object. I do not understand why `this.watch` of  MaClasse2 instance does not work when the value of att1 is changed. Can anyone explain to me.

Here is my corrected code:

```
        require(["dojo/_base/declare","dijit/_WidgetBase"],function(declare,_WidgetBase){

        MaClasse1 = declare([_WidgetBase],{
        });

        MaClasse2 = declare([_WidgetBase],{
        });

        var att1 = {'a':'att1_v1','b':'1234'};
        var maClasse1 = new MaClasse1();
        maClasse1.set('att1',att1);
        var maClasse2 = new MaClasse2();
        maClasse2.set('att1',maClasse1.get('att1'));
        maClasse2.watch('att1',function(name, oldValue, value){//<--- this doesn't work
            console.log("Execution du watch: ",name, oldValue, value);//<--- this doesn't work
        });//<--- this doesn't work
        console.log('Avant chgt: ',att1, att1 === maClasse1.get('att1'),att1 === maClasse2.get('att1'));
        att1.a = 'att1_v2';
        console.log('Après chgt: ',att1, att1 === maClasse1.get('att1'),att1 === maClasse2.get('att1'));
    });
```

Comment: please translate in English.

Answer (score 4):

`dojo/Stateful#watch` only fires when properties are changed via its `get` and `set` APIs.  You are effectively changing the value via direct assignment, which Stateful has no way of monitoring.

Watchers should fire properly if you change your `changerAtt1` method to the following:

```
changerAtt1: function (nv) {
    this.set('att1', nv);
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be inheriting both `_WidgetBase` and `Stateful`.  `_WidgetBase` already extends `Stateful` with new `get` and `set` methods, so you should only have to extend `_WidgetBase`.  Extending both is likely to cause bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've done the two modifications, you tell me, it does not work. –  Yvon PLANCADE 8 mins ago

Comment: @YvonPLANCADE: If it does not work, update your question and point out exactly what happens. Looking at your code, it is not clear that you correctly attempted this solution. You need to use `set` for `watch` to invoke your callback.